# NGINX URI With Period Proxy Pass Issue

Tags: java, nginx, tomcat, nginx-reverse-proxy

So we have a setup where nginx is our reverse proxy that uses proxy_pass to apache tomcat in several locations. The issue we encountered is this:

- If a URI contains a dot/period as a trailing value (e.g. http://example.com/sub/john-doe.), this is not properly forwarded to tomcat.
- As per the access log in tomcat, **"period"** was excluded/removed from the URI path.

(http://example.com/sub/john-doe.). --> (http://192.168.1.10:8080/sub/john-doe)

Testing directly to tomcat via local access (http://192.168.1.10:8080/sub/john-doe.) works fine. The **"period"** was not removed.

What is the correct configuration for this in nginx?

TIA

- nginx 1.19 (windows)

Common configuration

```
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
    add_header          X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";

    client_max_body_size    4000M;

    location /sub {
        proxy_pass   http://<ip>:8080/sub
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing special about a URI ending with `.` that would cause `proxy_pass` to behave differently. Are there any rules in your configuration file that specifically match URIs ending with a `.`?

Comment: None. We don't have any special rules applied. Modified the content for more info.